# Different way to pass uniforms to seperate draws in glMultiDrawElementsIndirect

Tags: opengl, glsl, c++

Given OpenGL version 4.3 and GLSL 430, what would be the best way to pass a matrix to each model in a draw call to `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect`?

I am thinking of going the way of a TBO and indexing it based on my own attribute passed in to each model that tells the shader which draw call it is currently on. That technique is not my favourite as I have to create another buffer for something that should be basic functionality for the type of draw call (think `gl_DrawID`), so I have come here to ask what I could do instead.

(`gl_DrawID` is **not** supported on my current system. Although it really should be: AMD catalyst 14.4 with OpenGL 4.4 support)